# Required field validator of the textbox

Tags: asp.net

I have one drop down and two text boxes for the start date and for the end date .The required field validator for the end date i'm enabling depending on the value of the drop down selected.

All of this validation part i'm doing inside the client side using the `ValidatorEnable()` built in function of the javascript which is calling due to `onchange()` function of the drop down.

All of this is working fine on the change of the value of the drop down first time. But when i'm doing the post back and during this there is a failure of some client side validation,the required field validator of the end date text box is not retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of code makes it hard to diagnose, but it sounds like you are only enabling validation based on value of the dropdown selected and only when the user changes the value of the dropdown... just do that same validation call when the page loads and not just when they select an item from the dropdown list. So on page load if the dropdown list has a previously selected value, your validation should get enabled and work as expected.

Also you should fix it where there is no postback on client side validation failure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Foolproof validation library that is available on Codeplex: https://foolproof.codeplex.com/

It supports, amongst others, the following "requiredif" validation attributes / decorations:

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]
```

Specifically I would suggest that you use the `[RequiredIfRegExMatch]` attribute.

To get started is easy:

- Download the package from the provided link
- Add a reference to the included .dll file
- Import the included javascript files
- Ensure that your views references the included javascript files from within its HTML for unobtrusive javascript and jquery validation.